# Is it possible to convert terraform into AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm, Planning to convert my existing implemented Terraform (Infrastructure as Service) Code into CDK.. Is it really possible??

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this as of version `0.5` of the CDK.
https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-cdk-for-terraform-0-5

1. Create a new directory
2. Initalize CDK project

```
cdktf init --template="python" --local
```

3. Copy over your `main.tf` file
4. Convert!

```
cat main.tf | cdktf convert --provider hashicorp/aws  --language python > imported.py
```

Answer (score 1):

My biggest concern actually is whether I'll be able to keep the existing infrastructure untouched when rewriting all my terraform modules into aws-cdk. Each construct in aws-cdk has a name which is used to generate a logical id in aws, and I'm not sure what's the equivalent one in terraform.

When running an aws cdk deploy, if a name is different from one that's in the cloud then it will destroy and recreate the resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to convert Terraform templates to equivalent CDK code.